# Deploying PhantomJS or headless gem on Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, xvfb, headless-browser, engineyard

I currently have an app deployed to Engine Yard. I am not familiar with importing chef recipes to Engine Yard's repo, etc. like a PhantomJS install. It appears the instance uses Amazon Linux. Is there a best practice, or even walkthrough, that would help me deploy either Xvfb or PhantomJS to my Engine Yard instance? Also, it is being used as a Rails application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [the PhantomJS gem](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem). It automatically installs PhantomJS the first time it's used, in a private location whose location you can get from an API. It provides a recent PhantomJS, currently 2.1.1. It works for me on both MacOS and Linux.

I haven't used that gem on Engine Yard, but I don't think there should be any Engine Yard-specific issues.

I use Cucumber, Capybara and poltergeist, so I have this in features/support/poltergeist.rb:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, phantomjs: Phantomjs.path)
end
```

Using Selenium-Webdriver directly, I'd expect what rantingsonrails suggested would work:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = Phantomjs.path
```

Comment: How did you implement the gem on engineyard, aka making sure the install is in the path etc?

Did you have to run something like this in a deploy hook?

    `phantom_path = Phantomjs.path`
    `Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = phantom_path`

Comment: I just deployed successfully running essentially the code in the last comment as an initializer. Just wanted to see if there was a best practice when using that gem with a PAAS?

Comment: I added to my answer. I'd say that's exactly how the gem and the drivers were designed to be used.